# Error opening streamreader because file is used by another process

Tags: asp.net, locking, streamreader

I am developing an application to read an excel spreadsheet, validate the data and then map it to a sql table.  The process is to read the file via a streamreader, validate the data, manually make corrections to the excel spreadsheet, validate again -- repeat this process until all data validates.

If the excel spreadsheet is open, then when I attempt to read the data via a streamreader I get an error, "The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process." Is there a way to remove the lock or otherwise read the data into a streamreader without having to open and close excel each time?

Comment: What happens if you mark your excel spreadsheet as read-only in explorer?  I think that Excel itself opens an exclusive lock on the file, but maybe by making the file read-only, other processes will be allowed to read it simultaneously.  I don't have excel, though, so I can't test that.

Comment: Good idea except that the user needs to be able to edit and save data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `File.Open` to get the stream are you using the overload that allows you to specify `FileAccess`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx

Note the parameters:

```
public static FileStream Open(
    string path,
    FileMode mode,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare share
)
```

You can pass `FileAccess.Read` to the third param to indicate you only need read-only access. You should also set `FileShare.Read` to allow others to open the file read-only instead of locking it yourself. Note that if MS Excel opens the file with FileShare.None, you probably wont be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you so much -- that works great. Just a note for others: I was able to set the FileShare to FileShare.ReadWrite that way I could edit the spreadsheet (csv file opened in excel) manually, save edits and still allow the mapping program to read the data.