# The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, io, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error opening streamreader because file is used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730565/error-opening-streamreader-because-file-is-used-by-another-process)

In C#, I am trying to build a program that copies a certain amount of files or directories that are listed in a textfile from one computer to another on the same network (ex. from "\PC_OF_MARK" to "\PC_OF_SARAH") However, I seem to be stuck at opening a stream with a streamwriter after having opened and closed a StreamReader.

Before I am able to copy anything, I need to be able to edit the contents of "files.txt" with my program.

On my form, I have 4 buttons: Add, Delete, Close and Copy.
I also have a ListBox lbItems that contains the lines from "files.txt".

The program is located in the Delete function: 
To delete a single line from "files.txt", I read the contents of lbItems and store them in a List. Next, I delete the string within the list that has the same index as the selected item in lbItems. Finally, I want to update "files.txt" by opening a StreamWriter (this is where the error occurs) and overwriting "files.txt" with the new List.

"files.txt" contains these 2 lines:

"%UserProfile%\Documents\files.txt" &
"%UserProfile%\Downloads\RubiksCube"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<string> envKeys = new List<string>();
    List<string> envValues = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDictionary ev = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ev)
        {
            envKeys.Add("%" + de.Key.ToString() + "%");
            envValues.Add(de.Value.ToString());
        }
        syncList();
    }

    private void syncList()
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Eigenaar\Documents\files.txt");
        string line = r.ReadLine();
        while (line != "")
        {
            lbItems.Items.Add(line);
            line = r.ReadLine();
        }
        r.Close();
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lbItems.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Ben je zeker dat je " + lbItems.Items[lbItems.SelectedIndex] + " uit de lijst wil verwijderen?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                List<string> array = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Eigenaar\Documents\files.txt"))
                {
                    string line = r.ReadLine();
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        array.Add(line);
                        line = r.ReadLine();
                    }
                    string t = r.ReadToEnd();
                }

                array.RemoveAt(lbItems.SelectedIndex);

                //Error occurs here:
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Eigenaar\Documents\files.txt", false))
                //The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Eigenaar\Documents\files.txt' because it is being used by another process.
                {
                    foreach (string str in array)
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(str);
                    }
                }
                lbItems.Items.RemoveAt(lbItems.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

If anyone knows what I'm talking about, please help!

Comment: Why don't you use File.Move ?

Comment: Can you give me an example, yorye?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the first

```
using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Eigenaar\D...
```

The `using` should result in the stream being disposed of, but that may not be closing the stream fast enough, I would try adding `r.Close()` at the end of the first `using` block. That might ensure that the handle is released so that you can open it again.

If that doesn't work, you can try opening the file as a read-share, so that it doesn't get locked.

Comment: Added r.Close(), but I still get the same error at the same location. As for your other solution, how do I open the file as Read-share?